# Curious about cin

Tags: c++, string, cin

I am very new to programming and trying to learn as much as I can. I am curious as to what cin char does exactly. When I input a word, the only thing outputted is the first letter of the word. Is this supposed to happen?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char ch;
cin >> ch;
cout << "Thank you for entering " << ch << endl; 
return 0;
}
```

I would like to output the whole word or phrase, but that does not seem to be happening. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: You're inputing into a char. A char cannot hold a word or phrase--it's a character.

Comment: In `c++` a string is `std::string`. Note that `cin` will stop at the first whitespace character so if your string has spaces you will want [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) Please look at the example in the link for getline. That should help a lot.

Answer (score 5):

A `char` is a single character. When that's the destination of your read, a single character is what you'll get.

If you want to read *multiple* characters (a string), then read into a `std::string` rather than a `char`.

To read more than a word (since `std::cin` will stop at whitespace), look into `std::getline`.

Comment: More so `std::cin >> std::string` will stop at whitespace, not `std::cin` itself.

Comment: Thanks! If I use std::getline is there a limit to the input?

Comment: @sungjina "is there a limit to the input?" - Yes. The end of the line. And also the amount of memory in your computer, if you input a crazily long line. There are *always* *some* limits.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

Yes this is supposed to happen. 
char in C++ is a type of variable that can only store a character. Therefore, cin will only take the first letter from the input stream. If you want to output a word use the string variable.

For more information on C++ variable types: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Comment: May I suggest using https://cppreference.com as a superior reference site to send people to, rather than cplusplus.com. cppreference is known to be much more complete and not full of factual errors..

Comment: @JesperJuhl, for what it's worth, as a new developer, I *much* prefer cplusplus.com because it's easier to read. cppreference.com may be more correct, but the "sugar" that cplusplus.com gives really helps the medicine go down.

Comment: @John In the long run you need to be able to read documentation without the "sugar". And factually correct and accurate documentation is worth more than easy to read (actually, I find cppreference to be quite easy to read; what's the problem?), incorrect documentation.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Noted.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll definitely be checking out cppreference.com and then cplusplus if I can't read the former haha.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you use `char` type. Char means 1 character of input string. Just use `string` type (included in **"string"** module).

**PS:** predicting your next question – you can use `cin.getLine()` function for reading whole input string next time. Because `cin` function read whole symbols until the `whitespace` character (as space  or `EOL` (end of line))

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to output the whole word or phrase, but that does not
>   seem to be happening

To output a whole word or phrase you have to reserve memory for the word or phrase.

Objects of the type `char` as in your declaration

```
char ch;
```

can store only one character.

Use instead an object of the standard C++ class `std::string`.
The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;

    getline( cin, s );

    cout << "Thank you for entering " << s << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Or without the using-directive (that is adviced)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s;

    std::getline( std::cin, s );

    std::cout << "Thank you for entering " << s << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there a reason I shouldn't use "using namespace std"?

Comment: @sungjina : [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5910058)